# Dynamodb efficient query on list

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index, partiql

I m porting a CosmosDB data model to DynamoDB. The objects look like that:

```
{ pk: "mypk", id: "myid", keywords: [ "lac", "sun", "nature" ] }
```

In CosmosDB I can make a query to the items of the list and hit an index, resulting in a fast and efficient query

```
SELECT * FROM c where c.pk = "mypk" and ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.keywords, "sun")
```

**In DynamoDB sort keys doesn't support list**, how do you deal with queries on list?
Should I go with a composite key something like "#lac#sun#nature" and do something like that in PartiQL:

```
SELECT * FROM "myTable" WHERE "pk"='mypk' AND contains("keywords", '#sun')
```

Or should I change the data design to allow efficient query but how?

Answer (score 0):

The Query in DynamoDB is still efficient unless you have a large amount of data that shares the same PK.

A composite key will not work as there is no `contains` function for a key.

I suggest you test your efficiency by using `ReturnConsumedCapacity` flag to see how much capacity you consume doing it the way it is. I'm guessing it's pretty efficient.

Comment: contains method exists, I tested with 
- sort key as string
- string set
- list

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html#Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.Functions

SELECT * FROM "myTable" WHERE "pk"='mypk' AND contains("keywords", '#sun')
and 
SELECT * FROM "myTable"."keywords-index" WHERE "pk"='mypk' AND contains("keywords", '#sun')

works for all type. the list seems slower than the string and string set, but I don't know if it's a scan or index search

Comment: That's causing you to Scan, which is inefficient. You cannot do `contains` on a sort key in an efficient way.